# Why is this (and other?) pizza oven so unnecessarily tall?

Tags: oven, pizza

I was watching a live stream from a pizzeria. I noticed that the oven appears to be at least twice the size vertically as it has to be. A pizza is flat and even with lots of toppings, it could very easily fit in half that size, or they could have two ovens stacked on top of each other if they need to make lots of pizzas at the same time.

But they just waste all that space for no reason? Why? Am I missing something? Other than just taking up more space, doesn't it also waste twice the electricity/fuel to keep so large of a space hot compared to half of it (vertically)?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: But you need a bit of heat distribution, be able to comfortably maneuver the pies and see the top of them to judge doneness?

Comment: I'll admit I don't get what is meant by "heat distribution", but they use those flat spades to easily manage the pizzas... The last point kind of makes sense, though, I guess, but isn't it time-based and standardized?

Comment: From experience baking bread in a bake house with huge wood-fired ovens: consider the case when you need to lift out one item from the back over those in the front. It’s not always feasible to go around.

Comment: Stephie, that sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Pizza ovens aren't unnecessarily tall. Pizza ovens often go three pies deep, depending on the size of the pizzas, so the space is needed to maneuver pizzas in and out, as well as to see how they are cooking. Many restaurants use the same ovens to bake pasta dishes, meatball heroes and other things which are thicker than a pizza, so the space is important there as well.

Comment: The oven also needs to be tall enough for people to be able to effectively access the interior to clean it.

Comment: Also, if the heating elements are too close to the pizza, it'll burn the pizza before cooking it.

Comment: @Max, that's not really the case, there's conveyor belt pizza ovens where the heating elements are very close to the pizza. It's the amount of heat they produce, not the proximity.

Comment: Yah -- I cook my pizzas with a gas flame about 4" away from the top of the pizza.  You actually want the heat very close.

Comment: To support this answer: smaller pizza ovens, designed to cook one pizza at a time, *do* have lower roofs.  https://ooni.com/products/ooni-koda-16